# Python subprocess: Giving stdin, reading stdout, then giving more stdin

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm working with a piece of scientific software called Chimera. For some of the code downstream of this question, it requires that I use Python 2.7.

I want to call a process, give that process some input, read its output, give it more input based on that, etc.

I've used `Popen` to open the process, `process.stdin.write` to pass standard input, but then I've gotten stuck trying to get output while the process is still running. `process.communicate()` stops the process, `process.stdout.readline()` seems to keep me in an infinite loop.

---

**Here's a simplified example of what I'd like to do:**

Let's say I have a bash script called `exampleInput.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# exampleInput.sh

# Read a number from the input
read -p 'Enter a number: ' num

# Multiply the number by 5
ans1=$( expr $num \* 5 )

# Give the user the multiplied number
echo $ans1

# Ask the user whether they want to keep going
read -p 'Based on the previous output, would you like to continue? ' doContinue

if [ $doContinue == "yes" ]
then
    echo "Okay, moving on..."
    # [...] more code here [...]
else
    exit 0
fi
```

Interacting with this through the command line, I'd run the script, type in "5" and then, if it returned "25", I'd type "yes" and, if not, I would type "no".

I want to run a python script where I pass `exampleInput.sh` "5" and, if it gives me "25" back, then I pass "yes"

So far, this is as close as I can get:

```
#!/home/user/miniconda3/bin/python2
# talk_with_example_input.py
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(["./exampleInput.sh"], 
                        stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
process.stdin.write("5")

answer = process.communicate()[0]

if answer == "25":
    process.stdin.write("yes")
    ## I'd like to print the STDOUT here, but the process is already terminated
```

But that fails of course, because after `process.communicate()', my process isn't running anymore.

---

**(Just in case/FYI): Actual problem**

Chimera is usually a gui-based application to examine protein structure. If you run `chimera --nogui`, it'll open up a prompt and take input.

I often need to know what chimera outputs before I run my next command. For example, I will often try to generate a protein surface and, if Chimera can't generate a surface, it doesn't break--it just says so through STDOUT. So, in my python script, while I'm looping through many proteins to analyze, I need to check STDOUT to know whether to continue analysis on that protein.

In other use cases, I'll run lots of commands through Chimera to clean up a protein first, and then I'll want to run lots of separate commands to get different pieces of data, and use that data to decide whether to run other commands. I could get the data, close the subprocess, and then run another process, but that would require re-running all of those cleaning up commands each time.

Anyways, those are some of the real-world reasons why I want to be able to push STDIN to a subprocess, read the STDOUT, and still be able to push more STDIN.

Comment: Check out [this article](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2017/interacting-with-a-long-running-child-process-in-python/) (specifically the section "Direct interaction with the child's stdin and stdout"). It looks like you'll need to do series of `.close()` and `.flush()` calls on stdin and stdout.

Comment: What no expect?

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is for. I would strongly suggest giving it a try over mucking around with subprocess directly, as pexpect abstracts away most of the stream handling details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you don't need to use `process.communicate` in your example.

Simply read and write using `process.stdin.write` and `process.stdout.read`. Also make sure to send a newline, otherwise `read` won't return. And when you read from stdin, you also have to handle newlines coming from `echo`.

*Note*: `process.stdout.read` will block until `EOF`.

```py
# talk_with_example_input.py
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(["./exampleInput.sh"], 
                        stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

process.stdin.write("5\n")
stdout = process.stdout.readline()
print(stdout)

if stdout == "25\n":
    process.stdin.write("yes\n")
    print(process.stdout.readline())
```

```sh
$ python2 test.py
25

Okay, moving on...
```

---

### Update

When communicating with an program in that way, you have to pay special attention to what the application is actually writing. Best is to analyze the output in a hex editor:

```
$ chimera --nogui 2>&1 | hexdump -C
```

Please note that `readline` <sup>[1]</sup> only reads to the next newline (`\n`). In your case you have to call `readline` at least four times to get that first block of output.

If you just want to read everything up until the subprocess stops printing, you have to read byte by byte and implement a timeout. Sadly, neither `read` nor `readline` does provide such a timeout mechanism. This is probably because the underlying `read` syscall <sup>[2]</sup> (Linux) does not provide one either.

On Linux we can write a single-threaded `read_with_timeout()` using [poll / select](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#module-select). For an example see <sup>[3]</sup>.

```py
from select import epoll, EPOLLIN

def read_with_timeout(fd, timeout__s):
    """Reads from fd until there is no new data for at least timeout__s seconds.

    This only works on linux > 2.5.44.
    """
    buf = []
    e = epoll()
    e.register(fd, EPOLLIN)
    while True:
        ret = e.poll(timeout__s)
        if not ret or ret[0][1] is not EPOLLIN:
            break
        buf.append(
            fd.read(1)
        )
    return ''.join(buf)
```

In case you need a reliable way to read non blocking under Windows and Linux, [this answer might be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4896288/3215929).

---

<sup>[1]</sup> from the [python 2 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readline):

> readline(limit=-1)
>
> Read and return one line from the stream. If limit is specified, at most limit bytes will be read.
>
> The line terminator is always b'\n' for binary files; for text files, the newline argument to open() can be used to select the line terminator(s) recognized.

<sup>[2]</sup> from `man 2 read`:

> ```
> #include <unistd.h>
>
> ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
> ```

<sup>[3]</sup> example

```
$ tree
.
├── prog.py
└── prog.sh
```

prog.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in $(seq 3); do
  echo "${RANDOM}"
  sleep 1
done

sleep 3
echo "${RANDOM}"
```

prog.py

```py
# talk_with_example_input.py
import subprocess
from select import epoll, EPOLLIN

def read_with_timeout(fd, timeout__s):
    """Reads from f until there is no new data for at least timeout__s seconds.

    This only works on linux > 2.5.44.
    """
    buf = []
    e = epoll()
    e.register(fd, EPOLLIN)
    while True:
        ret = e.poll(timeout__s)
        if not ret or ret[0][1] is not EPOLLIN:
            break
        buf.append(
            fd.read(1)
        )
    return ''.join(buf)

process = subprocess.Popen(
    ["./prog.sh"],
    stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE
)

print(read_with_timeout(process.stdout, 1.5))
print('-----')
print(read_with_timeout(process.stdout, 3))
```

```sh
$ python2 prog.py 
6194
14508
11293

-----
10506
```

Comment: This does solve my example, thank you! Unfortunately, for some reason, it doesn't carry over to my real-world problem. With this code, my output from proc.stdout.readline() is very truncated compared to the actual output. Not sure how to make a MWE for the real-world case. I'll put a screenshot below (top: python script, bot: first, output from terminal, then output via python script) link: https://imgur.com/hyNX8Jc

Comment: The latest update was precisely what I needed. The python script output now matches my command line output. This implementation is more straightforward than the pexpect solution suggested in the comments above. Thanks for your persistent work on this, Ente!