# Is it possible to interact with the subprocess 3 standards streams on windows?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, pipe, interactive

I have a script that opens a subprocess, this process awaits multiple inputs.

I tried with subprocess.Popen() but when combining the 3 standards streams it gets stuck in deadlocks...

So I tired to use wexpect (Apparently Windows version of pexecpt) it also didn't worked.

Now I'm using Sarge and my code right now looks like this:

```
import os
import subprocess
import sarge
import sys


def get_env():
    env = os.environ.copy()
    return env

def interactive(list_command: list, instruction_dict: dict):
    env = get_env()

    std_out = ""
    for a_number in instruction_dict:
        capture_stdout = sarge.Capture(buffer_size=-1)
        capture_stderr = sarge.Capture(buffer_size=-1)
        child_proc = sarge.Command(list_command, stdout=capture_stdout, stderr=capture_stderr,
                                    shell=True, env=env)
        child_proc.run(input=subprocess.PIPE,
                            async_=True)
        print(capture_stdout.readlines(timeout=1.0), capture_stderr.readlines(timeout=1.0))
        if instruction_dict[a_number][0] is not None:
            #if capture_stdout.expect(instruction_dict[a_number][0]) is not None or capture_stderr.expect(instruction_dict[a_number][0]) is not None:
            #    self.test_manager.log_event(msg="found line : " + instruction_dict[a_number][0] + "in PIPE", current_event_type=LogLevel.DEBUG, screen_only=False)
            print("in exec line : ", child_proc.stdout.readline(timeout=1.0), child_proc.stderr.readlines(timeout=1.0))
        else:
            print("in exec line : ", child_proc.stdout.readlines(timeout=1.0), child_proc.stderr.readlines(timeout=1.0))
        if instruction_dict[a_number][1] is not None:
            print(f"sending \"{instruction_dict[a_number][1]}\" to process in interactive")
            temp_bytes = str.encode((instruction_dict[a_number][1]+"\n"))
            child_proc.stdin.write(temp_bytes)
            try:
                child_proc.stdin.flush() # blind flush
            except:
                pass

        print("Last line : ", child_proc.stdout.readlines(timeout=1.0), child_proc.stderr.readlines(timeout=1.0))
        child_proc.wait()
        std_out += child_proc.stdout.read().decode('utf-8')
        child_proc.kill()    # kill the subprocess
        print("output: ", std_out)

interactive(list_command=["process.exe", "-delete_datamodel", "MODELNAME"],instruction_dict={1 : (None, "y")})
```

Output looks like this:

```
[] []
in exec line :  [] []
send "y" to process in interactive
Last line :  [] [b'User root connected to DB MODELNAME\r\n']
output:  Are you sure to delete DB MODELNAME? (y/n)\n\nDelete Data Model Ok\n
```

In console it looks like this:

```
C:\>process.exe -delete_data_model -db_name MODELNAME
Are you sure to delete DB MODELNAME ? (y/n)
y
User root connected to DB MODELNAME
Delete Data Model Ok
```

There are multiple problems:

- I can't catch the first stdout "Are you sure to delete DB MODELNAME ? (y/n)" during the loop I only get [].
- capture_stdout.expect crash but in fact it might be the same problem as the first one, if it can't read the first stdout.
- lines are going in stderr instead of stdout (it might be because of the process, I don't know how to test this)
- for another command I ll need to answer more than one interactive by looking of the question before answering them that way my instruction_dict will look like this

```
instruction_dict = {1 : ("Are you sure to recover the DB", "y"),
                                2 : ("Do you want to stop the service", "y"),
                                3 : ("Do you want to stop the DB", "y"),
                                4 : ("Do you want to drop and create the DB", "y")}
```

Is this even possible? I have search for a working exemple and didn't found one, I know I might be bad at searching but...

Sorry for the terrible syntax(and bad english), I want to know if there is a pure python solution (I have one solution working in tcl but I'm trying to get rid of it/ I didn't wrote the tcl code).

Comment: What do you mean by "the 3 PIPES"?

Comment: I meant stdout stderr and stdin but maybe the name isn't pipes. I'm new to scripting...

Comment: I fixed the title

Comment: You might want to look at this question. It is IMHO similar to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57225646/python-subprocess-giving-stdin-reading-stdout-then-giving-more-stdin

Comment: It's very similar, I'm trying it right now. Thanks!